# SQL Query with if-else logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some devices which have to be maintained every while, I created a SQL DB for time scheduling for those devices. Now I want to know the next maintenance date for each device.

I have four types of maintenances with interval for each one (like this)

```
CI ---------- 12000 Hour
HGPI-------24000 hour
CI2 -------- 36000 Hour
MI --------- 48000 Hour
```

I have created a table in my database for the maintenances, so each maintenance is being recorded and then recorded as done or not yet (like this)

```
M_ID  |  Device_ID  |  Device_Work_Hours  |  M_Type  |   M_Done  |  M_ExpectedDate
  1   |   1         |         25000       |  HGPI    |    NO     |    5-12-2019
```

I want to build query for those maintenance records with the following logic:

- If the maintenance of type CI is not done and the device working Hours is less than 24000 then to select CI Maintenance Record.
- If the maintenance of type HGPI is not done and the device hours is between 24000 and 48000 then to select HGPI even if the CI and CI2 are not done yet.
- If the maintenance of type MI is not done and the device hours is more than 48000 then to select MI what ever other maintenance types are not done.

I am Using MS SQL Server.
Please your help, SQL Experts.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What kind of SQL DB aka RDBMS?  From your profile I would assume MS Access?  Solutions may differ depending on the DBMS. Also, some simple sample data & the expected results would help out people who spend their free time on this. Best added as text, since one can't copy&paste from an image.

Comment: Try to  use `case when` for selecting data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there's also a table with the maintenance types. 
And that M_ID is the foreign key to that table.

Also assuming that there's an  M_Done number column that equals 1 when the maintenance is done.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM your_maintenance_table AS m
JOIN your_maintenance_type_table AS mtp
  ON mtp.ID = m.M_ID 
 AND mtp.Type IN ('CI', 'HGPI', 'MI')
WHERE (m.M_Done <> 1 OR m.M_Done IS NULL)
  AND 
   (CASE 
    WHEN mtp.Type = 'CI' AND m.Device_Work_Hours < 24000 THEN 1
    WHEN mtp.Type = 'HGPI' AND m.Device_Work_Hours Device_Work_Hours BETWEEN 24000 AND 48000 THEN 2
    WHEN mtp.Type = 'MI' AND m.Device_Work_Hours > 48000 THEN 3
    ELSE 0
    END) > 0;
```